# VBA decimal places program

Tags: excel, vba

I need a program that requires the user to provide a number with **no more than 2 decimal places**, and if a number with more than 2 decimals is given to loop back and ask again. Then to be able to output that number with the corresponding decimal places.
This is what I have so far...

```
Sub program()
   Dim num as Double

   num = Inputbox("Give me a number with no more than 2 decimal places:")

   MsgBox "Your time was " & num & " seconds."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Inputbox` use [Application.InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) with `Type:=1`. This will ensure only numeric entries.

Is this what you are trying? This will allow values like `1,1.1,1.11,.1,.11`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim digitsAfterDecimal As Integer

    Do
        Ret = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a number with max 2 decimal places", Type:=1)

        '~~> If user presses cancel
        If Ret = False Then Exit Do

        '~~> Number of digits after decimal
        digitsAfterDecimal = Len(CStr(Ret)) - InStr(CStr(Ret), ".")

        '~~> This will allow up to 2 decimal
        If digitsAfterDecimal < 3 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If Ret <> False Then MsgBox Ret
End Sub
```

Comment: Because this is marked as the answer, I expect you guys are talking implicit about Microsoft Excel, because in Microsoft Access `Application.InputBox` isn't available. So I will add a proper tag to the question.